# DataGridView bold only some words in the rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am using VS2012, C#. My DataGridView's datasource is connected to BindingList, and some of columns is made of snippets of text from solr. So, I would like to bold only words which were part of the search term. Something like that:

I was searching for **that word** and **that word**

I've found the way to bold whole row, but that's not it. I only need to bold particular words. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this answer:

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/403918/Formatting-part-of-a-String-for-a-datagridview-cel#answer2

Basically making just part of the text in the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn bold is not possible. Font is set for the whole cell. Control which enables that must be custom build.